# Mongodb WT_ERROR: non-specific WiredTiger error,

Tags: mongodb, wiredtiger

I've tried this command:
mongod --repair --dbpath  --storageEngine wiredTiger
and received the same error. 
Mongo version v3.4.9

Here is the error when I try to start mongo pointing to the now 
corrupt db: 
 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (-31802) [1529507255:694305][19415:0x7fffaa47b380], txn-recover: unsupported WiredTiger file version: this build  only supports major/minor versions up to 1/0,  and the file is version 2/0: WT_ERROR: non-specific WiredTiger error

E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (0) [1529507255:694388][19415:0x7fffaa47b380], txn-recover: WiredTiger is unable to read the recovery log.

=E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (0) [1529507255:694417][19415:0x7fffaa47b380], txn-recover: This may be due to the log files being encrypted, being from an older version or due to corruption on disk

E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (0) [1529507255:694445][19415:0x7fffaa47b380], txn-recover: You should confirm that you have opened the database with the correct options including all encryption and compression options

E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (-31802) [1529507255:694802][19415:0x7fffaa47b380], txn-recover: Recovery failed: WT_ERROR: non-specific WiredTiger error

[initandlisten] Assertion: 28595:-31802: WT_ERROR: non-specific WiredTiger error src/mongo/db/storage/wiredtiger/wiredtiger_kv_engine.cpp 269

I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 28595 -31802: WT_ERROR: non-specific WiredTiger error, terminating

I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...

I NETWORK  [initandlisten] removing socket file: /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock

I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...

I CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting

I CONTROL  [initandlisten] shutting down with code:100

Comment: Anything on this ?

Comment: no.  I ended up creating a new database.